# Use global data for different controllers in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller, global-variables

I'm kinda noob with CI so don't be too surprised:

I would like to set a variable within a controller and be able to use it in another controller.

For example:
In Controller 1:

```
$signup = FALSE;
```

In Controller 2:

```
if($signup == FALSE){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Would 'signup' be related to the state of a 'guest' user (model)? Would be one way of sharing user 'state information' across the system. i.e. there is always a 'guest user' you just do not know the specific details yet. These turn into a 'real' user when they 'sign on' after registering etc.

Comment: Well I have 3 controllers : visitor, user, admin.
I would like to load a specific homepage for the visitor when the admin click on a button.
I'm sure it exists a way better way to solve this but I wanted to make a global variable so that when the admin click on "close signup" button, visitors wont see a signup link on their homepage.
I don't know if i'm clear enough, english is not my native language.

Comment: Mhm I think the best way to do this is to maybe set a signup_switch variable in the database and then make a model.